# Anaconda Prompt (py27) can't find where conda is located

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am a newbie for Python and I've found Spyder way too complicated to make it work. Since my default Spyder's Python version was 3+, I couldn't use the guide that I've found so I installed Spyder for Python 2.7 somehow. Now I need to install scikit-image but Anaconda prompt doesn't recognize "conda" commands.

So I've found that I should check where conda is located first but the prompt cannot even find where conda is so I wanted to ask it to people here.

The left one is for default, the right one is for py27.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd3eN.png)

Comment: have you checked your path in your sys environments..?

Comment: just add C:\Users\[Your Username]\Anaconda3\Scripts to your enivornment path and restart the terminal, then try where conda

Comment: Yeah I've just added "C:\Users\%Username%\Anaconda3" and "C:\Users\%Username%\Anaconda3\Scripts" to the "Path" in the user variable and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! I'll add it as an answer and hopefully you will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add Anaconda path to your environment variables.

Your steps will most likely be:

- Windows: In your environment variables add `C:\Users\[Your Username]\Anaconda3\Scripts` to Path.
- Ubuntu: edit your `.bashrc` and add `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH`

A shortcut to opening env. vars.  in Windows: Open up your cmd and type:

`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author).*

Adding Anaconda3 and Anaconda3\Scripts paths to Path variable in the user variables has solved the problem.